# Files vs DB for storing logs

Tags: database, file, logging, server

I'm going to be as specific to my case as I can :

- I have log files on a per-user basis.
- I expect to have around 50,000 users to my application.
- Log files vary in size from 1KB to upto 50KB or more. Usually around 1-5KB.
- All users have an ID by which they can be referred to.
- Around 500 files will be created/modified per day, maybe upto 1500 on weekends.
- Only one server exists and uses an SSD.

Knowing this, would it be preferred for me to use files with the names as "log*ID*" or use a database? Besides this log file, there is not much other data like passwords or such which recommend databases.